# how can I use the formtastic with out wrapper_html? or change it.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I using it has a `<li>` tag wrapper the `<input>` tag always.I don't want it..

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using Formtastic only makes sense if you're happy with the code it generates.

Otherwise use [other form builders](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_form_builders), or the built-in helpers, or fix your CSS to fit Formtastic code.

Comment: couldn't agree more. Particularly formtastic has very strong markup opinions and you have little capability to extend/modify it. simple_form provides you with a little more flexibility, imo